# Which is the best way to filter data in two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the one below, just as an example of my dataframe (the list of tickers I have is very long). I would like to get a new dataframe where all the tickers which are accomplishing the 3 SOS signals `'Absorption Vol', 'Stopping Vol', 'Test in Rising'` appear as a result.

```
data = {
    'Ticker': ['SEDG', 'SEDG', 'SEDG', 'PEP', 'PEP', 'PEP', 'CTLT'],
    'SOS': ['Absorption Vol', 'Stopping Vol', 'Test in Rising', 'Test in Rising', 'Absorption Vol', 'Shakeout', 'Test'],
    'Date': ['2021-12-14', '2021-12-16', '2021-12-18', '2021-12-14', '2021-12-16', '2021-12-18', '2021-12-20']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Ticker             SOS        Date
0   SEDG  Absorption Vol  2021-12-14
1   SEDG    Stopping Vol  2021-12-16
2   SEDG  Test in Rising  2021-12-18
3    PEP  Test in Rising  2021-12-14
4    PEP  Absorption Vol  2021-12-16
5    PEP        Shakeout  2021-12-18
6   CTLT            Test  2021-12-20
```

The problem I have now is that I would like to filter the dataframe showing only the tickers with match in SOS column for `'Absorption Vol', 'Stopping Vol', 'Test in Rising'`. I need the condition that these 3 SOS signals need to be present for each ticker in order to be shown as a result. If only one of the SOS signals is matched and not the rest, the ticker should not appear.

The result I want is something like this, but extended for the huge amount of tickers.

```
  Ticker             SOS        Date
0   SEDG  Absorption Vol  2021-12-14
1   SEDG    Stopping Vol  2021-12-16
2   SEDG  Test in Rising  2021-12-18
```

I am trying this code, but it's not showing the ticker when all these 3 SOS signals appear, but when one does:

```
SOS_values_filter = ['Test in Rising', 'Absorption Vol', 'Stopping Vol']
rslt = final_df_sos[final_df_sos['SOS'].isin(SOS_values_filter)].groupby('Ticker').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3)
print(rslt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.groupby('Ticker')` *first*, then you can check if each group's SOS column contains the necessary values.

```
s = {'Test in Rising', 'Absorption Vol', 'Stopping Vol'}
df.groupby('Ticker').filter(lambda sf: s.issubset(sf['SOS']))
```

Output:

```
  Ticker             SOS        Date
0   SEDG  Absorption Vol  2021-12-14
1   SEDG    Stopping Vol  2021-12-16
2   SEDG  Test in Rising  2021-12-18
```

Here I'm using a set because the order of the input doesn't seem to matter. And I'm using `.issubset()` because I assume it doesn't matter if other SOS values are present as long as the necessary three are. You can customize this to your needs.

Comment: P.S. I'm not a Pandas expert so there could easily be a better way to do this that I'm not aware of.